# Excel Charts, Lining up Primary and Secondary Axis

Tags: excel, charts

I have tried to line up my axis', I like the units it is in, but if you look closely 2 hours on primary(duration) does not line up with 22:00 hours(time on clock). The goal is to be able to use the dashed lines on the secondary axis. As you can see when I add secondary axis the lines disappear.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this? I have tried several macros online but to no avail.

Here are my axis' before:

[image]

And after:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT~~~~~

I need help formatting this chart, would like primary axis to go from 20:00 to 8:00 am, when I do this all data stretches.

[image]

Comment: You have 12 hours on one side and 16 on the other.

Comment: @asp8811 , Hi,  How can I scale my secondary axis down from 20:00 to 8:00 am instead of 12? And keep it in line with my primary?

Comment: Right click on it and go to Format Axis. You should be able to set upper and lower bounds.

Comment: @asp8811 I do realize this, but very hard to do, I make them both the exact same, still off abit and need the secondary to go from 20:00 to 08:00.

Comment: Can you post your workbook somewhere so I can take a look at exactly what you have?

Comment: @asp8811 Is Dropbox good? Or do you got an email I can send to? I'd prefer email its easier for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107180/discussion-between-asp8811-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: To stretch the axis from 8PM to 8AM (overnight)you will need to use days in decimal form. 0.833333333333333 is 8PM of one day. and 1.333333333334 of the next day, because it is greater than 1.

Right click on the secondary axis, select format axis.

Set minimum bounds to 0.833333333333333
Set maximum bounds to 1.333333333334

Set major units to .041666666666667

Primary axis

Set minimum bounds to 0
Set maximum bounds to .499999999999999

Set major units to .083333333333333

[image],

Change the cell formatting of the cells holding data plotted on the secondary axis to HH:MM AM/PM if you want to change the time format on the secondary axis.

Comment: Thanks alot! Lines up nicely. When I am plotting my lines that are in the AM  on secondary axis they disapear?  is this a formatting issue? It works if it is before midnight, but in the morning they dont show.

Comment: So, you're not getting 0:00 through 8:00 on the secondary?